# Managing view frame when hide and unhide a tabbar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIViewController that has tab bar controller at bottom. When user click on a button I m hiding the tab bar. Tab bar is getting hidden but there is a white space at bottom. ViewController frame is not changing. How to manage this ? If tabor controller gets hidden, viewController height should get increase.

```
  func apply(_ effect: ActivityFeedEffect) {

    switch effect {
    case .feedTypeChange(mode: let mode):
        self.parent?.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = mode == .hidden
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension on UITabBarController, which you can use.

This basically, updates the frames of the view. 
You can add animation and other frame handling if needed, based on your use case. But this is something that can lead you in that direction.

```
 extension UITabBarController {
      func hideTabBar(isHidden:Bool) {
        if (isTabBarAlreadyHidden() == isHidden) { return }
        let frame = self.tabBar.frame
        let height = frame.size.height
        let offsetY = (isHidden ? -height : height)
        self.tabBar.frame.offsetBy(dx:0, dy:offsetY)
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + offsetY)
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func isTabBarAlreadyHidden() ->Bool {
        return self.tabBar.frame.origin.y < UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have configured on the storyboard the extended Edges to go under bottom bars and under opaque bars (see image). So My view always takes the hole screen, and I don't need to adjust the frame. Maybe this helps.

My structure is Tab bar -> Navigation Controller -> TableView (here I hide/show the tab bar)

[image: storyboard]